# How to use local gem with bundler

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

I have local ruby gem, with a development version forked from github. So I have it locally. Now I want to use it in my application. I'm using bundler so I did:

> gem 'otrs_connector', :path => '/devel/otrs_connector'

problem is that I get errors about missing files

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'otrs_connector'
```

then run

```
$ ruby app.rb 
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require': no such file to load -- otrs_connector  (LoadError)
```

how can I load my "under development" gem?

this is my /devel/otrs_connector

```
$ ls -al /devel/otrs_connector
total 112
drwxr-xr-x  15 marcinkrzyzanowski  staff    510 Oct  1 15:22 .
drwxr-xr-x  33 marcinkrzyzanowski  staff   1122 Oct  1 15:17 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 marcinkrzyzanowski  staff     55 Oct  1 15:04 .document
drwxr-xr-x  13 marcinkrzyzanowski  staff    442 Oct  1 15:04 .git
-rw-r--r--   1 marcinkrzyzanowski  staff    820 Oct  1 15:04 .gitignore
-rw-r--r--   1 marcinkrzyzanowski  staff    480 Oct  1 15:04 Gemfile
-rw-r--r--   1 marcinkrzyzanowski  staff    773 Oct  1 15:04 Gemfile.lock
-rw-r--r--   1 marcinkrzyzanowski  staff   1054 Oct  1 15:04 LICENSE.txt
-rw-r--r--   1 marcinkrzyzanowski  staff   2016 Oct  1 15:04 README.rdoc
-rw-r--r--   1 marcinkrzyzanowski  staff   1428 Oct  1 15:04 Rakefile
-rw-r--r--   1 marcinkrzyzanowski  staff      5 Oct  1 15:04 VERSION
drwxr-xr-x   4 marcinkrzyzanowski  staff    136 Oct  1 15:04 lib
-rw-r--r--   1 marcinkrzyzanowski  staff  16896 Oct  1 15:22 otrs_connector-1.3.0.gem
-rw-r--r--   1 marcinkrzyzanowski  staff   2954 Oct  1 15:04 otrs_connector.gemspec
drwxr-xr-x   4 marcinkrzyzanowski  staff    136 Oct  1 15:04 test
```

Answer (score 0):

Where is the file stored? I think you stored it in a `devel` folder in your home folder, not at `/devel`. If you start a path with a `/`, you points to the root of the HD path.

You might want to change the path to

```
gem 'otrs_connector', :path => '~/devel/otrs_connector'
```

(please note the `~` which is a replacement for the path to your home folder).

Comment: it's in "/devel/otrs_connector" not in home as you suggest. I put there full path to make sure that path is ok.